# How to disable Windows 11 File Explorer action bar?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, desktop-customization

I just switched to Windows 11 and it feel like it is made for touch screens (which I don't need). I don't need such huge paddings and action bars at all which waste space and reduce my productivity. Is there a way to disable the File Explorer action bar or reduce it in height, marked with a red square?

[image]

I had already checked "Decrease space between items (compact view)", and all it does is it just makes the file list the same as on Windows 10 which was a default.

Comment: I looked at a couple of Windows 11 machines and what you are looking at is built in, so I think you are out of luck on that issue.  You might consider xPlorer2 (Zabkat) as a replacement Explorer better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["action bar" is called "ribbon" or sometimes "command bar"](https://www.xda-developers.com/file-explorer-windows-11/). Currently, [it is not possible to minimize or hide it via any settings, registry etc.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-hide-the-ribbon-in-windows-11-file-explorer/f6cb766b-c358-4d82-b263-52c919369a00).

But there are several workarounds, the [reg hack](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-the-file-manager-command-bar-in-windows-11) doesn't work anymore, but you can bring back the Explorer with the old Windows 10 Explorer with it's ribbon (note, other features will change as well, for example, you won't be able to use tabs any more):

- Start the classic Control Panel: `control panel` via command line
- Use the "up arrow" or type Alt+UpArrow

[image]

This will give you the Explorer with the "classic ribbon" which you can minimize with the small arrow on the right top (it will stay minimized after you close and open it again):

[image]

Alternatively You can use the following command (e.g. use it in a cmd file and assign a hotkey):

```
powershell.exe -nop -ep bypass -c "& {"Start-Process \"Control\"; $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $null = $wshell.AppActivate(\"Control Panel\");Start-Sleep 0.8;$wshell.SendKeys("'"%{up}"'")}
```

There are a few other options [if you look for them](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/get-back-windows-10-ribbon-ui-windows-11/) including various 3rd party software e.g. [ExplorerPatcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) or [Windhawk](https://windhawk.net/) (personally I only used ExplorerPatcher so far). However, I find the control panel the easiest one.

Comment: Thanks, the ribbon layout is more compact for my needs and also faster since I think it doesn't use UWP?.. Will try using it until some tweak comes around that doesn't require constant running of some background apps (already tried ExplorerPatcher and Windhawk, latter had 8 processes running and 200MB of ram used).

Comment: do you mean the new or the classic ribbon?

Comment: I meant the classic ribbon (the win10 one).

Comment: @Rudolph thank you

Comment: Windhawk worked best for me. It takes almost no ram when the window is closed, which is only needed for installing mods.

Comment: +1 upvoted. Interesting fact.